# Page builder error after Upgrade from Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.2 on admin

Tags: magento, migration, magento2, upgrade, magento2.2

I am getting the following error after upgrading my website to Magento 2.4.2.

I navigated to Content > Pages. After that, I am getting this issue in the console. Page keeps on loading.

Error :
Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1/magento2.4.2/pub/static/version1618505838/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/slide/converter/attribute/overlay-color.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Anyone having idea on the same ?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?